# If you add some salt if or if you added some salt if

Tags: difference, conditionals

My mother is cooking, I am standing next to her and I want to say something about her cooking:

> (1) *If you add some salt, it will be better.*

> (2) *If you added some salt, it would be better.*

Which should I use? And what's the difference between the two sentences?

Comment: In principle, the "will" version is more "forceful" and the "would" version is more "polite, deferential". In *practice*, it makes absolutely no difference in your context talking with your mother. But if you were talking to your boss at work, you'd be more likely to use "would" in something like *If you gave me a pay rise I would work harder.* But you'd probably use "will" in *If you sack my best friend, I will resign.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I get it now. That's why native speakers often say *it **would** help if you **gave** some context* rather than *it **will** help if you **give** some context* when they want to explain something. The form "if + past, ... would + infinitive" sounds more polite, right? I always think that this structure is dependent upon an fullfiled situation. However, the second conditional can be used to make suggestions sound more polite. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Yes, that's the main thing - ***would*** goes with Past tense *[IF] **gave***, and ***will*** goes with Present tense *[IF] **give***. So long as you always get that right, you shouldn't need to worry too much about which to choose in any specific context. You probably know enough to make the right choice if it *actually* makes any difference; in any context where you're unsure, most likely it doesn't really matter. It's just inevitable in contexts like an ELL question that people will flag up (real, insignificant, or spurious) distinctions for just about every alternative phrasing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So the type 2 second conditional has two uses. 1. Used to talk about a imaginary situation. 2. Used to make suggestions. I thought the sentence *"if you added some salt, it would be better"* talks about a imaginary situation and unfulfilled. "Imaginary situation" and "make suggestion" aren't the same, aren't they? Both refer to a type 2 second conditional

Comment: @FumbleFingers What's difference between *"Will it be all right if I bring a friend tomorrow?* and *"Would it be all right if I brought a friend tomorrow?*

Comment: There's no meaningful difference. Use whichever you like.

Comment: My English grammar book (Practical English Usage) explains *"Will it be all right if I bring a friend tomorrow?"* (**direc**t) and *"Would it be all right if I brought a friend tomorrow?* (**indirect**). Does "direct" mean impolite? And "indirect" means polite. I don't understand the terms. Could you explain?

Comment: We're no longer talking about "English" as such. This is just a matter of how human beings interact, with or without language. If someone is standing in your way, you could gently nudge or forcefully push them aside - both of those are "direct" ways of communicating that you want them to move. Or you could say *"Get out of my way"* (or the equivalent in whatever language you both have in common).  That's relatively "direct". OR you could say something like *"**Will / Would** you stand aside, please?* I'm sure you can work out for yourself which of those is more "politely indirect".

Comment: @Nyambek, as I explained in your previous question, besides the levels of deference that the *would* version implies, there is also a separate nuance. Sentences of the form *If you **do** X…* can convey a neutral invitation to do *X*, whereas those of the form *If you **did** X…* can suggest that the speaker doubts the addressee’s willingness or ability to do *X*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The *"Would* you*...?  version is more polite. I feel I disagree with English grammar books that say *"Will you...?* is a direct way of communicating. What do you think I'm right? The direct way you have explained and I agree.

Comment: I think you're seriously overthinking this one.